# Postgresql argument placeholder in jsonpath expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, jsonpath

I try to pass argument **$1** to jsonpath-expression:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM %s.orders AS O WHERE order_info @? '$.items[*] ? (@.ProductID == $1)'
```

but it doesn't work. Postgresql is saying:

```
pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0
```

I tried to concat jsonpath-expression:

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM %s.orders AS O WHERE order_info @? '$.items[*] ? (@.ProductID == ' || $1 || ')'
```

But it also doesn't work. I use `sql` Golang package and lib/pq driver.

How I can pass argument to jsonpath expression?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the error for the second attempt? Same as for the first one?

Comment: No. Second error is `pq: syntax error, unexpected $end at end of jsonpath input`

Comment: hmm could that be an order-of-execution issue? What happens if you enforce the order by wrapping the jsonpath string with the concat into parentheses? e.g. `@? ('$.items...' || $1 || ')')::jsonpath`

Comment: If that doesn't work, try using the `json_path_*` functions, I believe `json_path_exists` would work for your case here, and to pass the parameter you would construct the `vars jsonb` argument using the `jsonb_build_object` function.

Comment: @mkopriva First variant is doesn't work too. What is `json_path_exists` function? I can't see this in PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: Sorry it's json**b**_path_exists, you can find it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your answers. But I resolved this problem by another way: `WHERE order_info @? CONCAT('$.items[*] ? (@.ProductID == ',$1::text,')')::jsonpath`